# SQL Query GROUP BY MIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to SQL just started learning yesterday so please accept my apologies if this is, in fact, an annoying newb question. I'm studying SQL as part of a college course.

I have a flat student database that I had to import into MSaccess. I have been given this task:

The courses with the least number of enrollments

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

As you can see by looking at the Enrollments there are 10 courses with 8 enrollments. My question is, how do I group all the minimum values in the Enrollments column?

I first tried this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN Enrolments AS Leastnumberofstudents 
FROM 
    DataFIle;
```

But of course, that only returns the minimum value of that column which is 8.

Then I tried:

```
SELECT [Course Name], MIN (Enrolments) AS [Least Number of Students]
FROM DataFile
GROUP BY (Enrolments), [Course Name]
ORDER BY (Enrolments), [Course Name];
```

But that returns all of the courses not only the ones with the minimum value.

[image]

I also thought about just using WHERE = 8 but I don't think that's what I'm being asked to do.

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be so apprenticed and again apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DataFile WHERE Enrolments = (SELECT MIN(Enrolments) FROM DataFile);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked great, I didn't know you could do that with the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `order by` and `select top`:

```
select top 1 df.*
from datafile as df
order by enrolments asc;
```

This assumes you are using MS Access.

Comment: This also worked and thank you so much. Please don't reply to this if you don't want to but what does df mean? If I want to do some reading on it what should I search for?

Comment: @JamesJPN . . . It is a table alias, an important part of the SQL language.  The default is the table name and people who use MS Access often use the default, even though the queries are then much longer than necessary.